# A non well formed numeric value encountered in PayPal

Tags: php, paypal, prestashop

Have an error in my PayPal module on my Prestashop site. It says

[30-Oct-2018 10:37:19 Australia/Sydney] PHP Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/public_html/modules/npaypalpro/ajax.php on line 214

Line 214 is

```
$amountCheck += number_format($item['quantity'] * $item['price'], 2);
```

Any ideas what might be the cause?

PHP7.1 on the server

PayPal said

> I quickly checked the transaction logs and found that there is mismatch in total amount and item amount.
>
> For one of the order, total amount is AUD 2337.30 but the sum of item
>   details are AUD 2339.30
>
> Item Details :
>
> Hikvision 6 MB - 180.90 x 7(quantity) = 1266.30 AUD Hikvisiion 4
>   channel - 535.50 x 2(quantity) = 1071.00 AUD Shipping – 0 Voucher
>   Taxes – 2.00 AUD – Which is not added in the total amount.
>
> Could you please ask the web developer to check how Voucher taxes are
>   getting added or to see why this is not passing in the API call?

Full function

```
function totalAmountCheck($amount, $items)
{
    $amountCheck = $diff = 0;

foreach ($items as $item)
    $amountCheck += number_format($item['quantity'] * $item['price'], 2);

if ($amountCheck != $amount)
    $diff = number_format($amountCheck - $amount, 2);

return $diff;
```

}

Comment: Are you using a module to apply an additional fee?

Comment: @idnovate no the module links with PayPal via the API. There was a discount applied to a product with taxes included. We tried turning off taxes but it still didn't like it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the format of the content in the variables, you can solve it by replacing it with this:
`$amountCheck += number_format((int)$item['quantity'] * (float)$item['price'], 2);`

Comment: thank you I will give that a try and report results back

Comment: just attempted payment with changes and received the generic failed error.

Comment: Creating a .htaccess folder in the PayPal module worked for me

This is what I used

    #In order to change the version to 5.5 -

    <FilesMatch "\.(php4|php5|php7|php3|php2|php|phtml)$">
     SetHandler application/x-lsphp55
     </FilesMatch>

Working now

Comment: @PaulD What kind of error exactly, the same error?, because your solution was change the php version, that's not a solution, php 7 is much better and optimized than php 5

Comment: Same error, but the developer said 

" I haven't this issue with other sites so server settings might have something to do with it (maybe different character encodings cause PayPal to be more strict?). Without looking at the site and debugging i wouldn't be able to tell you what's going on with the other modules :/. As for this one this seemed to do the trick."

Problem

$amount = $ps_amount; // float

Resolution:

$amount = (string) $ps_amount; // string

// The payload is then turned into json by php and send by cURL

With his fix there was still issues though

Answer (score 0):

Paypal wants the exact price.

For example:

If your cart is 25 euro for 2 products plus 5 euro of shipping, you must to passing the shipping too.

in this case you **must** to pass the **Voucher Taxes**.

Paypal say: you want 2339.30 AUD but your cart is 2 AUD less.

Comment: Have tried buying another Paypal module but having issues with that one too. Might be PHP7.1 or could be something else. More likely PHP 7.1 as everything works fine in PHP5.6

Comment: It's just strange that PayPal would have a hissy fit on PHP7 but not PHP5.5